# Select without creating any locks but read committed records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to write a sql select statement without creating any locks in tables but read committed records.

Can someone help please...

Comment: `with nolock` will not lock the table, but you get dirty data.  I'm not sure you can have it both ways.

Comment: I think that's a contradiction.  No locks will get you all records, committed or otherwise.

Comment: I want to read committed records but without locking any tables

Comment: You cannot have it both ways.  If you want to read only committed records, then you need to lock the table.  Also, if you want ensure that the records retrieved are consistent with each other (i.e. they were all in the table together at some point in time) then you need to lock the table.  You may not need *explicitly* to do so, however, depending on the configured transaction isolation level.

Comment: Note, too, that even locking the table doesn't prevent you from reading uncommitted records that were created/modified earlier in the same transaction that performs the read.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading/Selecting data under default transaction isolation level doesn't lock the table, but it obtains something called Shared Locks on the resources, It means multiple users can read the same rows all obtaining Shared Locks on the resources.

And when a user modifies a row it obtains an Exclusive Lock on the resources. Exclusive lock means no one else can access the data while its being modified. It is exclusively locked by that user.

Therefore moral of the story is stick to Default Transaction Isolation Level `Read Committed` and it will obtain a lock (shared lock) on the row before retrieving it, to avoid Dirty reads.

Otherwise less strict isolation level read uncommitted does not obtain any locks and will result in dirty reads.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option.  With that option on, row versioning instead of locking is used to provide the default READ_COMMITTED isolation behavior.

There is some cost when this option is enabled.  There is an additional 14-bytes for each row plus the overhead of maintaining the row version store in tempdb.  However, the overhead can be more than offset by concurrency improvements depending on your workload.  You also need to make sure applications are not coded to rely on the default locking behavior.